# Convert String column to JSON in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am currently having table with one column name `event` (string) in athena external table and i just want to get that value as a JSON. I am using below query but it converts it into string:

```
select CAST(event AS JSON) AS json_event from table);
```

output is appending `\` with every double quote `"`

value in table:

`{"att1": "a", "att2" : "a2"}`

above query after CAST() return:

`"{\"att1\": \"a\", \"att2\" : \"a2\"}`

Moreover, when i run query:

```
select json_event.attribute
from
(select CAST(event AS JSON) AS json_event from table);
```

it throws exception:

```
TYPE_MISMATCH: line 1:8: Expression json_event is not of type ROW
```

Am i doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) to get JSON value deserialized from the input JSON text:

```sql
select json_parse('{"att1": "a", "att2" : "a2"}');
```

Output:

```
          _col0
--------------------------
 {"att1":"a","att2":"a2"}
```

**UPD**

The `event.userid` syntax can be used to access fields of [`ROW`](https://trino.io/docs/current/language/types.html#row) datatype, not `JSON`, if you want to extract some information from JSON string you need to use different approaches (depending on what actually is needed). For example in this particular case you don't need even to parse the string as JSON just use [`json_extract_scalar`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract_scalar) (can be used both on `varchar`'s and `JSON` types):

```sql
select json_extract_scalar('{"att1": "a", "att2" : "a2", "id": 42}', '$.id');
```

Output:

```
 _col0
-------
 42
```

Comment: i tried this already but it is throwing same error if i query further attributes from that parsed json:

`select event.userid from
(SELECT json_parse(event) as event
FROM test)`

it complains:
`TYPE_MISMATCH: line 1:8: Expression event is not of type ROW`

Comment: @vicky the query in the answer works. What is returned by `select typeof(event) from test`? Ideally provide a [mre] with sample data and types.

Comment: `typeof(event)` return `json`

Comment: @vicky so it is already json, why do you want to cast it to json? If you want to turn it to string, use `json_format`

Comment: sorry for this. Actually column data type is string, i am using below query to first get the string in json and then i am trying to query inner attributes:

`select event.userid from 
(SELECT json_parse(event) as event
FROM table)`

Comment: @vicky So 'json_parse` is working and the problem is in the following processing. Which is completely another question. I will update the answer in few minutes.

Comment: Actually even if i try `SELECT json_parse(event).userid FROM table` it is throwing same error: `TYPE_MISMATCH: line 1:8: Expression json_parse(event) is not of type ROW`. So may be i am missing something here cox i am not much experienced with aws athena or presto. Thanks for the help

Comment: @vicky - see the update. I hope it will clarify things.

Comment: May be i have to read presto for all this but for now i am fine with this. Thanks for the prompt help! cheers